# why the SharePoint online site menus and action links are still showing in Italian langue although i change my language inside my profile

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, language

I created a modern communication site and i set its default language as English :-

[image]

And the service account's default profile language created by our IT admin was Italian >> So i changed the settings to English and logout then relog in:-

[image]

but still the menu items and action links inside the above site is showing in Italian language instead of English, any advice:-

[image]

[image]

So any advice why the menu items and action links are not set based on my profile settings' language, which is english?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check your site language settings. Maybe you have only Italian language on this settings. You can use this link if you don't know how do this:[MSDN INFO](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-the-languages-for-a-sharepoint-site-user-interface-16d3a83c-05ab-4b50-8fbb-ff576a3351e8)